# Best software to do big number calculations quickly

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, mathematical-software

I am trying to do some work on some math conjecture. I am testing the conjecture numbers using very large math numbers (100+ digits ). I am currently using python to test these numbers.

In the conjecture's calculation, I quickly need to multiply and divide a large number several times. Python can do this quickly(~3000 calculations per minute). Is there any other faster software to achieve this.

Comment: https://gmplib.org/ is used in http://www.flintlib.org/ is used in SageMath.

Comment: I use PARI-GP for number theoretic calculations. It's pretty fast for big-integer calculations, though I've never benchmarked it for 1000+ digits. But I have certainly done calculation using numbers larger than that. It's free, so you could check it out: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/

Comment: If you are comfortable with C++, you might have a look at the [BOOST Multiprecision Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: pari-gp is fastest when gmp is used : https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/benchs/pari-2.10.0-72240911/timings-int.html . I think boost also uses gmp at the back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it would seem to belong better on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have used https://www.shoup.net/ntl/ productively and I am not by any reasonable standard a competent C++ coder.